# Spring Boot - Timed Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following Spring Boot Web Application and used Tomcat as a server and Thymeleaf for my html templates. I have two questions regarding my first Spring Boot project.

This is how my code looks like so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myIpAdress")
private String displayMyIpAdress(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception
{
    model.addAttribute("myIpAdress", getMyIpAdress());
    return "myIpAdress";
}

private String getMyIpAdress()
{
    // here is a simple HTTP Request returning my IP Adress from a server
}
```

This is the myIpAdress.html

```
<div th:text="${myIpAdress}"></div>
```

All it does it displaying my IP Adress on my view, works great. Nothing fancy so far.

**First question:**
How do I set up a timer, to display my IP every second on my html File? I want an IMMEDIATE change in my View as soon as my IP changes. In Java I would simply do a scheduled timer or code a while(true) loop with a Thread.sleep(1000L) like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    while(true){
        System.out.println("My IP is: "+getMyIpAdress());
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    }
}
```

This Java code works VERY fast. The console displays my IP adress almost every second. Which is exactly what I wanted initially. But now I wanted to make a Spring Boot Web App out of it and it is incredibly slow and the request takes up to 15 seconds to make the request and render the view.

**So my second question** is, why is it that slow? And how can I improve the speed? I don't have any CSS or JavaScript running on the HTML file, it really only displays my IP adress.

All I want is to fetch the IP from the server and display it on my view. Every second. How do I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

In pure Thymeleaf you can't update the static view every time something changes in your backend without sending a new request from the client side. It works one way only - requests are from the client to the server, not the other way around.

The easiest way to achieve what you want to do is to add a simple javascript  to the template which fetches the IP address every second (eg. from a special dedicated endpoint) and updates the view.

Or you could add some [websocket support](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) to the template, but I don't think it's needed in your case (seems to be an overengineering)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is there a template engine that works two ways?
It doesn't have to be thymeleaf. It can be pure Spring Boot too, I dont mind as long as it works like a charm.

Comment: It's not the template engine being the problem here, Its the way the client communicates with the server. You can add the websocket support to have a two way communication. Also, "long polling" can be an option. 
I don't know which template/frontend library provides it the nicest way, though.

Comment: Also, as I said, you're probably fine with a simple javascript that sends request for the ip every second in the Thymeleaf template.